# Get HTMLFormElement object from Jquery submit()

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

So I have this snippet which captures the submit:

```
$(function(){
    $('#xhr2_form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        sendForm();
    });
});
```

and this snippet to apply the XHR 2 form submission

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

function sendForm() {
    var myForm = $('#xhr2_form');

    // get fields
    var values = {};
    $.each($('#xhr2_form').serializeArray(), function(i, field){
        values[field.name] = $(this).val();
    });

    // append data
    var formData = new FormData(myForm);
    formData.append('type',values['type']);

    xhr.open('POST', '/test/xhr2', true);
    xhr.onload = function(e){};

    xhr.send(formData);
}
```

the problem is the api for FormData accepts an HtmlFormElement as documented here:

http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/XMLHttpRequest-2/#the-formdata-interface

the problem is I'm trying to retrieve that HTMLFormElement from the submit event of Jquery, but I don't know how.

without JS, this is how it's done:

```
<form id="myform" name="myform" action="/server">
  <input type="text" name="username" value="johndoe">
  <input type="number" name="id" value="123456">
  <input type="submit" onclick="return sendForm(this.form);">
</form>

function sendForm(form) {
  var formData = new FormData(form);

  formData.append('secret_token', '1234567890'); // Append extra data before send.

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', form.action, true);
  xhr.onload = function(e) { ... };

  xhr.send(formData);

  return false; // Prevent page from submitting.
}
```

so how do I get the HTMLFormElement in Jquery?

Comment: Just a hint, jQuery has built in support for getting form data from a form like so: `$('#id_of_form').serialize()` <-- text in querystring-format. This makes it so you can reduce your code a lot.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Is the issue just that you're providing a jQuery object instead of a DOM node? If that's the case, you should be fine just retrieving the first element from the object, which (unless you have something invalid like another `xhr2_form` on the page) will give you the form element you're looking for.

```
function sendForm() {
  var myForm = $('#xhr2_form'); // this is a jQuery object

  // ...

  /*
   *  myForm is a jQuery object
   *  myForm[0] is the first element of the object, in this case whichever
   *    node has the ID "xhr2_form"
   */
  var formData = new FormData(myForm[0]);

  // ...
}
```

You could also retrieve it using [`.get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) (not to be confused with [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)) like so:

```
$("#xhr2_form").get(0);  // or myForm.get(0);
```

Also, as a side note, when you use jQuery to search for an ID, like `$("#some_id")`, after it's determined that [`some_id` is a potentially valid ID](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js#L333), it [uses `getElementById` to find the node anyway](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js#L449-456).

Answer (score 3):

I not sure to understand your problem.

To get the HTMLFormElement, simply use : 
`document.getElementById("myform")`

```
alert(document.getElementById("myform")) ; // Return HTMLFormElement
```

Or with jQuery :

```
alert($("#myform")[0]);  // Return HTMLFormElement
```

Answer (score 0):

In the event itself, the value of `this` should be the form element.  Alternately, you can access the event's original element via `$(e.target)` or `$(e.originalTarget)`

Comment: this is a sample code for an XHR2 tutorial, does Jquery support XHR2?

Comment: Ahh, I missed that point, edited my answer and removed my pondering.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('#xhr2_form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        sendForm($(this).parents('form'));
    });
});
```